# Couldnt use $_GET value

Tags: php, get

Before that, I searched around for problem same as me, but not found any..

I got a url `http://mywebsite/rpc.php?stat=22`

then, I have this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['stat'])){
$id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $_GET['stat']);
$result = $rpc->get($id);
print_r($result);
}
```

this code will print array without result..
But, If I modify the code like this :

```
if(isset($_GET['stat'])){
//$id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $_GET['stat']);
$result = $rpc->get(22);
print_r($result);
}
```

it will print the result as I want..
I tried echoing $_GET,and it output number 22..
is there anybody know what is the problem with my script?

this is the code that will process `$rpc->get();`

```
public function get ( $ids = array(), $fields = array() )
{
if ( !is_array( $ids ) ) $ids = array( $ids );  // Convert $ids to an array if only a single id was passed
if ( count( $fields ) == 0 ) $fields = array( "id", "name", "downloadDir", "rateDownload", "status", "doneDate", "haveValid", "totalSize" );    // Defaults
$request = array(
"fields" => $fields,
"ids" => $ids
);
return $this->request( "torrent-get", $request );
}
```

Comment: `$_GET['stat']` is `'22'` while you are explicitly supplying `22`. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I never know about that..
tried method from Jeff Sisson and it works :) thank you for explaination @WaleedKhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$rpc->get` method seems to want an integer as the parameter, which you can get from the `$_GET` global like this:

```
$id = intval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $_GET['stat']));
```

Comment: I dont know this could be the problem :)
thank you for the solution.. it works like a charm..

Comment: At this point you may as well just use `intval($_GET['stat'])`. Both will attempt to convert it to a number (though in different ways), but this would be simpler.